# mkdir(): No such file or directory Error using Storage class

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have been encountering this Error all day long, I have googled the error and tried every possible solution, but till now i have no idea why i'm seeing this ..!
I'm trying to create "Albums" with id for each one 
my function goes like this :

```
public function store(AlbumRequest $request) {
try {
  Album::create($request->all());
  $lastRec = Album::latest()->first();
  $dir = base_path() . '\Albums'. '\\' . $lastRec->id;
  //dd($dir);
  $file = Storage::makeDirectory($dir, 0775, true, true);
  $message = '<div class="alert alert-success">Album Added Successfuly </div>';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
  dd($e);
  $message = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Something went <strong>Wrong</strong>, Please try again later!</div>';
}

return redirect('/home')->with(['message' => $message]);
```

}

and thin as you see I'm fetching the last record, to capture the incremented id after that using the ID im making a directory named with the ID 
dd( the path ) out puts the following path :

```
"C:\Users\Mohab\slp\Albums\20"
```

and every time gives me the same error :

```
ErrorException {#245 #message: "mkdir(): No such file or directory"
```

any help please !!

Comment: do you have C:\Users\Mohab\slp\Albums\ folder ?

Comment: Do you really want to use your base_path here?  Seems like it'd be much better to use the storage_path to keep things clean.

Comment: @fico7489 yes i do

Comment: @Devon i tried storage_path and also public_path neither of them worked !!

Comment: @MohabEl-Sayed, so `file_exists($dir)` returns true?

Comment: @Devon i didn't try it, but when i dd($dir) it out puts the path correctly Like i said in the question

Comment: @Devon it outputs false though, $dir is suppose to be a path string that makeDirectory () to make ?!!

Comment: If it outputs false, then the path doesn't exist.  file_exists returns true for files and directories